# How to solve MySQL error Error Code: 1005 Can't create table 'proj.#sql-75c_18' (errno: 150)?

Tags: mysql

Presently I am facing problem in adding foreign key constraints. I am getting Error Code: 1005 Can't create table 'proj.#sql-75c_18' (errno: 150). How to resolve this error?

I have Residence table with some coulmns. And I am creating another table Called Residence_Atorny with 4 columns.

```
Create table residence_atorny(
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   residenceAtornyId BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `residenceId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `fk_residence_atorny_residence` (`residenceId`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_residence_atorny_residence` FOREIGN KEY (`residenceId`) 
   REFERENCES `residence` (`ResidenceId`))
```

And for Residence table I want to add 'residenceAtornyId' as forein key for residence table.

```
ALTER TABLE residence ADD COLUMN residenceAtornyId BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE residence ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_residence_residence_atorny` FOREIGN KEY (residenceAtornyId) REFERENCES residence_atorny (residenceAtornyId);
```

Comment: Check [14.6.6 InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html): `InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.`. Be careful because you will be generating circular constraint.